# Do we have Hilchot Shotrim (Policemen laws)?

Tags: halacha-theory, beit-din-court

> "מִצְוַת עֲשֵׂה שֶׁל תּוֹרָה **לְמַנּוֹת שׁוֹפְטִים וְשׁוֹטְרִים** בְּכָל מְדִינָה וּמְדִינָה וּבְכָל פֶּלֶךְ וּפֶלֶךְ שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים טז יח) "שֹׁפְטִים וְשֹׁטְרִים תִּתֶּן לְךָ בְּכָל שְׁעָרֶיךָ".
>   שׁוֹפְטִים אֵלּוּ הַדַּיָּנִים הַקְּבוּעִין בְּבֵית דִּין וּבַעֲלֵי דִּינִין בָּאִים לִפְנֵיהֶם.
>   **שׁוֹטְרִים אֵלּוּ בַּעֲלֵי מַקֵּל וּרְצוּעָה וְהֵם עוֹמְדִים לִפְנֵי הַדַּיָּנִין הַמְסַבְּבִין בַּשְּׁוָקִים וּבָרְחוֹבוֹת וְעַל הַחֲנֻיּוֹת לְתַקֵּן הַשְּׁעָרִים וְהַמִּדּוֹת וּלְהַכּוֹת כָּל מְעַוֵּת וְכָל מַעֲשֵׂיהֶם עַל פִּי הַדַּיָּנִים וְכָל שֶׁיִּרְאוּ בּוֹ עִוּוּת דָּבָר מְבִיאִין אוֹתוֹ לְבֵית דִּין וְדָנִין אוֹתוֹ כְּפִי רִשְׁעוֹ**: ([Rambam Sanhedrin 1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Sanhedrin_and_the_Penalties_within_their_Jurisdiction.4?lang=he))

IIRC, that's all we have on Shotrim. Rambam himself does not mention Shotrim in Sefer Hamitzvos. In addition, just as the Mitzvah of Judges wasn't abolished so, seemingly, shouldn't the commandment on Shotrim.

What happened to the commandment to appoint Shotrim and what Halochos, besides that Rambam, do we have?